# An algebraic inequality with three components

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Consider
>   $A^2  = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2$, $B^2  = b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2$ and $C^2  = c_1^2 + c_2^2 + c_3^2$.
>
> Is the following inequality always valid, for $\forall a, b, c > 0$?
>   $$AC - 4AB \le (a_1c_1 + a_2c_2 + a_3c_3) - 4(a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3)$$

I am trying to prove that this inequality holds. It is the final step in a larger problem that I am working on (these are vector components). Please help.

What I have tried:

(a) Expand the LHS. This got very messy because of the square root exponent, and I didn't know how to proceed.

(b) Try various numbers for $a, b, c$ using brute-force, but I know this is not a sufficient method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality $AC-4AB \le (a_1c_1 + a_2c_2 + a_3c_3) - 4(a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3)$ is not true for all positive reals $a_i$, $b_i$, and $c_i$. To observe that, consider $a_1=a_2=a_3 = 1$, $b_1=b_2=b_3=2$, $c_1=1$, $c_2=2$, and $c_3=3$. It is easy to verify that $AC-4AB \color{red}{>} (a_1c_1 + a_2c_2 + a_3c_3) - 4(a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3)$ in this case.

Comment: I am so sorry, there is a typo - which I am now correcting. That should be $\forall a, b, c > 0$. The values $a, b, c$ are non-zero. Can you please take another look / give another hint?

Comment: @Max Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Answer accepted. Something must have gone wrong in my vector component calculations then.